# $K^n \cong K^m \implies n = m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $K$ be a field and let $E$ be a vector space over $K$. I want to prove that any two finite bases of $E$ are equinumerous. What I did was:

Let $B = \{u_1, \cdots, u_n\}$ be a finite basis of $E$. Consider:

$$f: K^n \longrightarrow E$$

Defined by $f(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i u_i$

It can be easily shown that $f$ is an isomorphism. It follows that $K^n \cong E$.

Let $B_0$ be any other finite basis of $E$, say of cardinality $m$. In a similar reasoning to above, we can prove that $K^m \cong E$.

It follows that $K^n \cong K^m$.

Now, how do I show that $n = m$?

I know that an isomorphism preserves the algebraic structure, that's, if two objects are isomorphic, then what is true about a designated part of one object's structure is true about the other's. That's why one feels that $n = m$ should be true. But how do I prove that rigorously?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: try using the basis $B =\{(1,0,\dots,0),(0,1,0,\dots,0),\dots,(0,0,\dots,0,1)\}$ for $K^n$.

Comment: The proof that in any space 2 basis are equinumerous is typical in many books, can be shown following this:
1. Show that A vector space $V$ over $F$ has a finite basis iff it's isomorphic to some $F^n$ (You did that).
2. Show that every finitely generated vector space $V\neq \{0\}$ has a basis. (Perhaps have that)
3. Showing that if there are two lists of vectors of the same length such that one generates V and the other is l.i, then both are bases.
4. (Corollary of 3). If $x_1,...,x_n$ generate V and $y_1,...,y_m$ are independent then $m\leq n$. And applying 2 times 4, you have the result.

Comment: Might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces

Comment: Thanks @JoeJohnson126, but I'm interested in this particular method. More specifically, I want to prove what is in the title.

Comment: I believe the proof on Wikipedia is what you want.  Any isomorphism from $K^n$ to $K^m$ can be represented by a matrix.  If there are more rows than columns, then the rows must be linearly dependent.

Comment: @Ahmed Your intuition in the last paragraph is a bit like the cart leading the horse.  You're expressing the concept of dimension being an invariant property ("designed part") of a vector space, but this is precisely what you need to prove.  Here's a very loose analogy: it isn't true that $U \times W \cong V \times W \implies U \cong V$ for arbitrary vector spaces $U,V,W$ over $K$, even though the same "designated part" argument might seem to apply here.

Comment: @ErickWong, I realize that this kind of reasoning is circular. However, this is not what I was thinking. I was careful not to consider the dimension as an invariant property, because I am yet to prove that it is actually well-defined. I was thinking that they must "look" alike in some sense, and that's why I said: one "feels" that $m = n$.

Comment: @Ahmed Thanks for the clarification, and apologies for my misunderstanding.  Note that if $E$ is an arbitrary vector space over $K$ then $E^2 \cong E^3$ is possible, so there really is something special about being finitely generated over $K$; that's why I suspect you'll need an argument of similar strength to what Joe Johnson suggests.

Comment: In characteristic $0$, the $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}$property $\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)$ of the trace (where $A,B$ are matrices so that both products are defined) gives a short proof: Suppose $f\colon K^n \to K^m$ is an isomorphism. Let $A$ be the matrix of $f$ and $B$ the matrix of $f^{-1}$, both with respect to the standard bases. Then $$n = \tr I_n = \tr (BA) = \tr (AB) = \tr I_m = m.$$ Unfortunately, that doesn't work for positive characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has essentially already been answered in the comments, I will present a solution anyway.  It's obvious that $K^n$ has a basis of cardinality $n$, namely $\{(1,0,\ldots,0), (0,1,0,\ldots,0), \ldots, (0,\ldots,0,1)\}$, so to prove that $K^n \cong K^m$ implies $n = m$, it's enough to prove that any two finite bases of a vector space have the same cardinality.  The simplest argument to show this that I know of involves successively exchanging elements of one basis with the other and is given in the Wikipedia articles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces#Alternative_Proof and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma.

To illustrate this proof by example, suppose that the vector space $V$ had a basis $B=\{v,w,x\}$ of cardinality $3$ and a basis $B'=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ of the larger cardinality $5$.  Then, since $B$ is a basis, $a$ must be a linear combination  of $v$, $w$, and $x$: 
$$\alpha v + \beta w + \gamma x-a=0.\qquad (1)$$
 Also, since $B'$ is a basis, $\{a\}$ must be linearly independent, which means that $a\ne 0$.  Therefore, at least one of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ must be nonzero; this means that we can rewrite $(1)$ to express one of the elements of $B$ as a linear combination of the other elements of $B$ together with $a$.  Assuming without loss of generality that the nonzero coefficient is $\alpha$, we can express $v$ 
 as a linear combination of $w$, $x$ and $a$:
$$
v=-\alpha^{-1}\beta w-\alpha^{-1}\gamma x+\alpha^{-1} a.
$$  Therefore, since $B=\{v,w,x\}$ spans $V$, $\{w,x,a\}$ must also span $V$.

We can now perform the same step again: write $b$ as a linear combination of $w$, $x$ and $a$:
$$\epsilon w + \zeta x + \mu a-b=0.$$
Since $\{a,b\}$ is a subset of the basis $B'$, it is linearly independent, so either $\epsilon$ or $\zeta$ must be nonzero.  This means that we can express either $w$ or $x$ as a linear combination of the other elements of $\{w,x,a\}$ together with $b$.  Assuming again without loss of generality that we can express $w$ in this way, $w$ is a linear combination of $x$, $a$ and $b$, and so $\{x,a,b\}$ must span $V$.

Performing the same step one more time, in the same way, we find that $\{a,b,c\}$ must span $V$.  Therefore, $d$ is a linear combination of $a$, $b$, and $c$, which contradicts the linear independence of $B'$ and hence the assumption that $B'$ was a basis.  Since we can clearly perform a similar argument for any two finite bases of unequal cardinalities, we can conclude that any two finite bases of a vector space must have the same size.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I can do a google search, and I don't need someone to link them to me in an answer; I am capable of understanding the proofs as well. What I'm wondering about is whether it is valid (hence how) to deduce that $m = n$ starting from $K^n \cong K^m$. So essentially, you had not answered the question.

Comment: There is no simple, automatic way to proceed from $K^m\cong K^n$ to $m=n$.  To do that, you have to prove invariance of basis number.  To take $m=1$ and $n=2$ and to put it in category-theoretic terms, there are categories containing elements $A$ so that $A\cong A\times A$.  It's just that the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces is not such a category.  So, you should not expect to be able to prove this without some effort.